# Python: List index out of range (Reversing a String)

Tags: python-3.x

I have read answers regarding the topic and figured out why the "list index out of range" occurs, **but I can't seem to locate exactly what I have to do to correct my code**. I am a beginner, hence may have ignored proper writing ethics.

The code is to reverse an already provided string but I am writing in a way so that I can start taking input from the user of an unknown number of words and it would still work.

```
teststring = "this is a test"
result = []

result = teststring.split()     #holding individual element

final = []                      #to hold the reversed string
#print(result)
z = int(len(teststring) - 1)    #number of elements minus 1
#print(len(result))
count = 0
count = int(count)
#print(result[count])
for i in result:
    p = int(z - count)
    final[count] = result[p]
    print(final)
    count += 1
#print(count)
print(final)
```

The Error I am receiving is this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/pi/python/15_Reverse_String.py", line 15, in 
>      final[count] = result[p]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if you wanna just reverse a list just do this  `result[::-1]`

Comment: That did work :D Thanks. Though just out of curiosity, I want to understand how the logic of my code is failing...

Comment: the variable `final` is empty and you can fill a list that way. You can even try to do this `empty = [] final[2] = 4` and you'll get the same error. Use `append` instead

Comment: `"".join(x for x in reversed(teststring))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're understanding about Lists in Python is wrong! I think you consider Python Lists like C++ Array. They differ in some concepts. Lists in Python are dynamic.
The `append` methods add something to the end of the array.If the array was empty, adding one element, it becomes the first element, the second becomes the second element and so.

```
teststring = "this is a test"
result = []

result = teststring.split()     #holding individual element
lenght = len(result)
final = []                      #to hold the reversed string
#print(result)
for i in range(1,lenght+1):
    final.append(result[i*(-1)])
print(final)
```

In Python you can access to the last element in List using index [-1], and you can access the element before the last element using index [-2] and so on. I use this technique to reverse the list.
for example in your case:

```
result[-1] = test
result[-2] = a
.....
```

Comment: Yes, I thought arrays everywhere work like the work in C++. So, your solution means it's important to use the append statement for this to work? And could you please guide me in the right direction on `result[i*(-1)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna reverse a list just do this result[::-1]

Answer (score 0):

Did you realise that `z = int(len(teststring) - 1)` returns the size of `teststring`?

You used that number as an index to access to the `result` array which consist of the tokens of the `teststring` variable.

This is a correct version of your code:

```
teststring = "this is a test"
result = []

tokens = teststring.split()     #holding individual element

final = []                      #to hold the reversed string

for i in range(len(tokens) - 1, -1, -1):
    final.append(tokens[i])

print(final)
```

But the optimal solutions are:

1. Use `tokens.reverse()` function. This function reverse your array.
2. Use `tokens[::-1]` trick. This trick returns the reverse of your array so that you need to save into a variable.

Comment: `for i in range(len(tokens) - 1, -1, -1):` in this part the len(token) -1 is the first value of i which is the last index of given list, second -1 stands for the last value of i ..and the last -1 suggest the range goes in opposite direction.. am I right?